# Getting error "montage.exe: unable to create temporary file '-': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/476.;"

Tags: java, imagemagick, montage

I'm using ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q8 and ghostscript(gs9.20) to create thumbnails of a pdf file.

Upon calling "`ProcessTask pt = montage.getProcessTask(op, (tag!=null)? (tag+":-") : "-" , "png:-");`" I'm always getting error

```
[Thumbnails] Process failed for 'TMP-2
000843':  montage.exe: unable to create temporary file '-': No such file or dire
ctory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/476.; montage.exe:  `png:-' @ error/montage.c/M
ontageImageCommand/1775.;
org.im4java.core.CommandException: montage.exe: unable to create temporary file
'-': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/476.
        at org.im4java.core.ImageCommand.finished(ImageCommand.java:253)
        at org.im4java.process.ProcessStarter.runAndNotify(ProcessStarter.java:3
67)
        at org.im4java.process.ProcessTask$1.run(ProcessTask.java:71)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Why are you using montage. That is for combining multiple images into one image. Should you not be using magick (which is the IM 7 version of convert) or magick mogrify?

Comment: There are multiple documents in our list,for which I need to create thumbnails.That's why I'm using it. Can you share the code snippet of magick implementation

Comment: If you want to process multiple image in a given folder then you should use mogrify with IM 6 and magick mogrify in IM 7 in command line mode. Montage combines several image into one collage of image. Do you need to do that after thumbnailing the images? Sorry I do not know JMagick only the command line. Functionally, what are you trying to do -- create thumbnails and then montage them into one file? Please explain what you are trying to do in words or use pictures.